# Form does not send input to MySQL in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I wanted a user to input data into the form, after clicking "Create", it shows that it successfully added the data. However, it doesn't appear in my MySQL Database, it only triggers the auto-increment of ID, other columns have no data.

Here's the code for the button CREATE:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Module DBConnection
Public Function strconnection() As MySqlConnection
Return New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=bankmanagement")
End Function
Public strcon As MySqlConnection = strconnection()

```
Public result As String
Public cmd As New MySqlCommand
Public da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Public dt As New DataTable
'for create or add function
Public Sub Create(ByVal sql As String)
    Try
        strcon.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = strcon
            .CommandText = sql
            result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If result = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to save data!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved in the database (Please click the Refresh button)", "SUCCESS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        strcon.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is my SQL Query for adding something on the form:

```
Private Sub SButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    Try
        Create("INSERT INTO customer (cust_name,cust_add,phoneNo) VALUES('" & cust_name.Text & "', '" & cust_add.Text & "', '" & phoneNo.Text & "')")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

What is the possible error here? Although the program runs in succession?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even going to guess how it's not erroring on you.  Guessing since it is actually inserting a blank record it's hiding the actual error.    Aside from that, you're creating a sql string.  Start by inspecting that in the debugger to ensure correct, then even try copy/paste into your SQL workbench and execute it directly.

Comment: That said, string concatenation to build SQL commands is kind of flawed.  You would be far better off changing your Create method to accept a MySqlCommand and parametrise your insert statement

Comment: Note: You are prone to MySQL Injections, please search on how to use **[parameters](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1201569/How-do-I-parameterized-the-queries-of-VB-NET-code)**.

Comment: @OptiShen I created a program using your code and it's working fine. I didn't encounter any problem, all columns in database are filled. Maybe you are trying to insert blank data so you get blank columns?

Comment: Everyone thank you for your answers, the problem for me is that I used some kind of template (like Guna, but its free) and it affected how my data was processed. Its weird but it now already works as I now changed my textbox to the textbox provided by Visual Studio.